# overhead of copying: doubles vs pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, double, copying

> the overhead of copying two doubles can be noticeable but often less
>   than what a pair of pointers impose

from C++ prog. lang.

could someone explain it?

Comment: Please add the relevant context, what is that person talking about?

Answer (score 2):

This is taken from Chapter 11 of "The C++ Programming Language" by Stroustrup.

Let's look at the quote in context:

> We defined the `complex` operators to take arguments of type `complex`. This implies that for each use of a `complex` operator, each operand is copied. The overhead of copying two `doubles` can be noticeable but often less than what a pair of pointers impose (access through a pointer can be relatively expensive). Unfortunately, not all classes have a conveniently small representation. To avoid excessive copying, one can declare functions to take reference arguments. For example:

```
class Matrix {
      double m[4][4];
public:
      Matrix();
      friend Matrix operator+(const Matrix&, const Matrix&);
      friend Matrix operator*(const Matrix&, const Matrix&);
};
```

All he is saying is that, since `complex` is small, it is acceptable to pass it around by value rather than by `const` reference. This, however, would not be acceptable for larger types, such as `Matrix` above. For such type, passing by `const` reference is the preferred method since it would avoid having to copy the whole matrix.

Comment: this is clear, but why The overhead of copying two doubles can be less than what a pair of pointers impose?